# Como redirecionar uma página usando .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, css

como tens passado? Bom, venho enfretando um problema que se resumo no seguinte:

Eu quero através do arquivo **.htaccess** redirecionar **apenas a página inicial** do meu site para um outro domínio. Exemplo:

Redirecionar: www.site1.com.br -> www.site2.com.br

Caso tenha outras páginas nesse mesmo domínio (**Exemplo**: www.site1.com.br/algumacoisa), **não deve redirecionar** para o segundo domínio (www.site2.com.br).

Comment: Eu acho mais fácil fazer isso com o php

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer isso usando php? Poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Estava errado o código, fiz uma edição

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o php você pode colocar na sua index da seguinte forma:

```
$siteAtual = str_replace(["www.", "http://", "https://"], "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
if($siteAtual == "meusite.com" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/"){
    header("Location: http://www.novosite.com.br");
}
```

- **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** - pega a URL principal
- **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** - pega o que tiver depois da URL principal

Se o que tiver depois for vazio, redireciona o cidadão.

Comment: Isso é exatamente oque eu preciso, obrigado! ☺